# Javascript: Make a cell editable

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a project with javascript. I have a button that inserts rows to my table. Each row has 3 cells. One of these cells have to be editable,so the user can write a link there. How can i achieve this? Thanks.
**I SHOULD NOT USE JQUERY!**
mycode :

```
<head>
<style>
table, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Insert(){
var x=document.getElementById("myTable");
var row=x.insertRow(1);
var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
cell1.innerHTML=document.getElementById("myTxt");


}


 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <input id="myTxt" name="Text1" type="text" />
 <input onclick="Insert()" name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Insert" />

 <table id="myTable">
 <tr id="myRow">
 <td>Cell 1</td>
 <td>Cell 2</td>
 <td>Cell 3</td>

 </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: When you generate your table, you have to have it inside a FORM tag.  With that, you generate an INPUT text box in whatever cell you need to make editable.

Comment: To expand on the above, there is no such thing as an 'editable' table cell. You need a text input control inside the cell. If you format it properly it can even look as if the cell itself is editable. Also you only need it inside a form tag if you plan to submit the contents. If you will just process them with JavaScript the form is not necessary.

Comment: @SunKnight0 How can i have an input control inside the cell , as you say?

Comment: `<td><input type="text"  name="AA" id="AA" value="Cell 3"/></td>`

Answer (score 2):

This would insert an input box into cell 1 in javascript:

```
function Insert() {

var x=document.getElementById("myTable");
var row=x.insertRow(1);
var cell1=row.insertCell(0);

var txtBox = document.createElement("input");
txtBox.type = "text";
txtBox.name = "Text1";
txtBox.id = "myTxt";

cell1.appendChild(txtBox);

var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
var cell3=row.insertCell(2);    

}
```